# Anyway to run C# code in remote process(E.g. IIS)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

Some of my website is not working well in production environment, sometime crash and sometime exception.
Since these websites are really old, some of them don't have enough log to troubleshoot.
I know i can add code one by one to have enough log, but it is huge work load and may impact the existing logic.

so what i am trying to do is:
**without modify any existing product code**,
can we attach or inject code into website process in runtime, then i can execute some code to log exception, http request and http response.
my environment is Asp.net 4.0+ and IIS7+

if i can execute my code in product process, it will be much easier to log without modify product code, the code will like this:

```
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                ///write log...
            };
```

unhandle exception is one of the case, i have several other case that i want to apply to all production, like:

1. log all request and response (i can enable log and disable log in
   anytime, from a remote management system)
2. Log unhandle exception
3. log swallowed exception
4. get a dump
5. monitor application, once condition reached(e.g. exception count,
   time out, memory usage)  trigger some action
6. print all stack when exception or unexpected return value ( with
   parameter and local value that function reference)

there is several tech point i can't find solution for now...

Answer (score 1):

If it's a web application and you're dealing with unhandled exceptions, you can add logging into global.asax; it may or may not help but seems like it will give you more insight than what you have so far.

Now, technically speaking, one can argue that modifying global.asax is modifying production code, but I took your question to mean that you don't want to go and modify hundreds of places in production code, etc.

Comment: yes, modify hundreds of production is huge work and may cause manual mistake, so i want to find a programmticall way to enable log,exception and other feature.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to add an error logging *module* to IIS.

See, for example, [SharpBrake](https://github.com/airbrake/SharpBrake), which has an IIS Module called [NotifierHttpModule](https://github.com/airbrake/SharpBrake/blob/master/src/app/SharpBrake/NotifierHttpModule.cs) that automatically catches all exceptions thrown by the site without any modification of the site's code.  (The only thing you need to do is include the module initialization in your `web.config` file.)  You could write something yourself based on SharpBrake, or ....

In fact, for what you are doing, you might consider using a service like [AirBrake.io](https://airbrake.io/pages/home) or its free open-source clone [ErrBit](https://github.com/errbit/errbit) to do the logging, and then you can use SharpBrake to do the error catching.